# cambiar el formato a mostrar de un campo date en mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql

Como puedo cambiar el formato que se muestra una fecha:

Para mostrar las fechas de una tabla, se muestran asi:

- 2016-06-28
- 2016-06-29
- 2016-07-01
- 2016-07-03

Y queria cambiar ese formato de muestra por uno asi:

- 2016, 06, 28
- 2016, 06, 29
- 2016, 07, 01
- 2016, 07, 03

Este es el código con el cual estoy mostrando mis fechas:

```
<?php 
include 'conexion.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM venta";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["fecha_emision"]."<br>";

}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Alguna forma de como hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrías solo que formatear el date

```
date("y,m,d", strtotime($row["fecha_emision"]));
```

eso te generaria el formato de fecha en la que lo requieres

Comment: y como podría mostrar las fechas de forma "ascendente"?

Comment: en tu consulta tendrias que hacer esto `SELECT * FROM venta ORDER BY fecha_emision ASC`

Answer (score 1):

Aunque es mas fácil como te ha comentado [Miguel Osorio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/9874/miguel-osorio), yo lo suelo tener con una consulta php.

```
function cambiaf_a_normal($fecha,$caracter){ 
   ereg( "([0-9]{2,4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})", $fecha, $mifecha); 
   $lafecha=$mifecha[1].$caracter.$mifecha[2].$caracter.$mifecha[3]; 
   return $lafecha; 
}
```